Is it necessary to to inform the person you have cursed about the curse?
When Rishi Shringi cursed Parikshit raja then Shringi ji's father informed through a Brahmana to Parikshit that he has been cursed to die.Is it compulsory to inform the person who has been cursed about curse?
Are there any examples where curse was given without the presence of person being cursed and not been informed of the curse?

It is sad to receive a curse uninformed, but, of course, that reflects victim's prārabdha karma!

Are there any scriptural references where curse was recieved uninformed?

Lord Shiva had cast a curse on a forest near Kailasa, that turned all male creatures living or entering the forest to become females. This was to give women companionship to his wife, Parvathi devi. Sudyumna, son of Manu, entered the forest unknowingly and turned into a woman. After realizing that he had lost his manhood, he sought the help of Forest Goddess. She modified the curse by chanting a spell - “You will be a woman only when the moon wanes and a man when the moon waxes.” Fortnightly, his sex changes. This too was a sad incident of uninformed curse!

Where is it mentioned sir?

Any examples from Padma,vayu,vishnu,garuda,varaha,bhagavata puranas(sattvika puranas) or mahabharata ramayana etc?

I) King Sudyumna Becomes a Woman [srimad bhagavatam, 9th Skandha Chapter-1], refer:
https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/9/1/
II) On the birth of Pururavā [Devī Bhāgavatam, First Skandha;, Chapter-12] refer: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/devi-bhagavata-purana/d/doc57111.html

and III) Creative Activity of Manu: The Story of Sudyumna [Vayu Purana  part-2 chapter-23, slokas: 1-28] Refer: https://kausiki.com/read/book/VAYU-MP-2-ASIS-ENG/25

Vālmiki Rāmāyanam [Book-IV: Kishkindhā Khānda, Chapter-11] says that Vāli was cursed uninformed by Matanga Muni (मतंग मुनि) who was living in an ashram (आश्रम) in Rishyamūkh Parvat (ऋष्यमूक पर्वत) of Kishkindhā(किष्किंधा). This post discusses about the sequence of events that lead to that unfortunate and sad incident.
Sugreeva reports to Rāma about the incident that sparked off the indignation and ire of Vāli towards him in sarga[9]. There was a fierce demon named Maayaavi, the elder brother of Dundubhi and the son of one demon named Maya. He that Maayaavi arrived at the doors of Kishkindha in a night and challenged Vāli for a fight. Vali came out of palace in all his anger to kill that great demon. That demon speedily entered an un-enterable cavity under the ground, covered with grass, and we too having reached there   speedily stood at the aperture of that cavity for a while. Then Vāli said to me, "Now you stay here on the alert, Sugreeva, at the entrance of this hole till I return on destroying the enemy in a fight on my entering this hole."
Well over a year is over after his entering into that cleavage, and to me too who stayed at the entrance of the cleavage that much time had passed away. After a long time blood with foam gushed out that hole, and Sounds of screaming demon came to my ear, but the screeches of my brother who is involved in fight are unheard, in the least. I have surmised and concluded in mind by the indications that my brother is finished, and covered the cavity's opening with a mountain similar boulder, and performed water oblations to my deceased brother with saddening pain, and then returned to Kishkindha. But the ministers have persuaded and heard from me the actual happening though I was concealing it. Then duly summoned by all of those ministers I was crowned, and while I was ruling the kingdom judiciously, oh, Raghava, that semi-human Vāli returned on killing that demoniac enemy. But on seeing me crowned his eyes were reddened in anger, and he arrested all my ministers as he spoke rudely. Oh, lord Rāma, though I bowed with the crown touching his feet, he that rancorous Vāli showed no quarter towards me.".
In sarga [11], Sugreeva narrates Vali's bravery and intrepidity in fighting and how he fought with a mountainous buffalo demon named Dundubhi who was the brother of the slain Maayaavi. Also narrated is the curse of Matanga Muni that prohibited Vali's entrance into Rishyamuka Parvatam (mountain area).

That great mighty demon Dundubhi wearing the look of a buffalo with
sharp horns was awe-inspiring, and like the arrival of a massive
dark cloud in rainy season full with water on the edge of firmament,
he arrived at the gateway of Kishkindha and bellowed clamorously
like a war-drum as though to quake the earth. [4-11-25, 26]
He bellowed uprooting trees that are rooted nearby, scooping the
earth with hooves, and insolently goring the gateway with horns like
a goring elephant. [4-11-27]
Vali who by then went into his palace chambers became intolerant to
hear that noise and fell out from there along with ladies, like the
moon with stars. [4-11-28]
Then Vali laughed that demon off, discharged all the females namely
Tara and others, and then he spoke to that stupid lord of demons in
anger. [4-11-37]
Don't surmise that I am drunk, and should you be unafraid of a
fight, regard this drunkenness of mine as the toast of a gallant
fighter in this deadly fight." Vali said so to Dundubhi. [4-11-38]
Saying that way to that Dundubhi that highly enraged Vali heaved up
the golden chest-pendant around his neck on to his chest, which was
given by his father Mahendra, and stood firm for fight. [4-11-39]
Then that elephantine monkey Vali took that mountain-similar
Dundubhi by horns, and booming highly he whirled and bumped him onto
ground. [4-11-40]
Vali while blaring highly with great sound repeatedly whirled him
and thrown onto ground, and while Dundubhi was hurled and thrown to
ground, blood gushed out of his two ears. [4-11-41]
There occurred a gruesome fight among those two, Dundubhi and Vali,
who by their fury are impetuous and who aspired victory over the
other. [4-11-42]
Then Vali who is similar to Indra in his fortitude fought with him
with his fists, knees and feet, and like that with boulders and
trees. [4-11-43]
While each is assaulting the other in that fight between that
monkey and demon, that demon is impaired and Indra's son Vali
toughened. [4-11-44]
In that life-taking fight when Dundubhi is lifted up and flung to
ground, he is completely pounded out. [4-11-45]
While he is felled down much blood is flown out from the vent-holes
of his body, nine of them, ears, nose, eyes etc., and on his
falling that mighty one Dundubhi attained the fifth-state.
[4-11-46]
Then the hastiest Vali swayed that dead and inanimate demon with
both of his hands and hurled him a yojana distance in a single
flick. [4-11-47]
And while he is thrown that hastily blood drops oozed from his
mouth, and flung by air they fell in the hermitage of sage Matanga.
[4-11-48]
On seeing the blood drops fallen there, oh Rama, that sage is
enraged and thought, 'who is he indeed, who dropped the blood...'
Thus Sugreeva narrated to Rama. [4-11-49]
'By which evil-spirited one I am abruptly touched with blood? Who
is that evil-minded one? Who is that malevolent, disobedient and a
reckless one?' Thus the sage Matanga pondered. [4-11-50]
Thinking thus and coming out of hermitage that celebrated sage has
seen the mountainous buffalo fallen on ground lifelessly. [4-11-51]
On knowing by his ascetic power that this deed is done by the
monkey, he released a great curse on him who tossed the cadaver of
buffalo. [4-11-52]
Untreadable is this sheltering wood of mine to him who has stained
it with squirts of blood, and if he enters this place peradventure,
fatality occurs on him. [4-11-53]
By his hurling the demon's body these trees are also completely
destroyed, hence he ought not set his foot in a distance of one
full yojana around this hermitage, and if that evil-minded one
places his foot then he evidently does not exist. [4-11-54, 55a]
And some of his friends that are dependent on my woods shall not
live here and they may depart on hearing my words and solace
themselves with my words. [4-11-55b, 56a]
This forest of mine is always protected like my own son, and if the
monkeys of Vali wish to stay behind in this forest alone for
further destruction of leaves or sprouts, or even for the
non-existence of fruits and tubers of this forest, defiantly they
too will be cursed. [4-11-57]
And today is the day of limit and the monkey whom I will see
tomorrow, he will be petrified for many thousand years to come.
[4-11-58]
Then those monkeys on hearing the clear wording of the sage started
out from that forest, and on their coming to Kishkindha, Vali saw
them and spoke this way to them. [4-11-59]
Why all of you dwellers of Matanga forest arrived in my presence,
even so, are you the dwellers of that forest safe?' Thus Vali asked
all. [4-11-60]
Then all of those monkeys have reported to Vali, the one with a
golden chest-pendant, all the reasons for their exit, likewise the
curse to Vali. [4-11-61]
Then on hearing all those words narrated by monkeys Vali approached
that great sage and begged of him on becoming humble with
palm-fold. [4-11-62]
The sage inconsiderate of Vali's request withdrew into hermitage,
and fearing to bear the brunt of the curse Vali was distraught and
withdrew from that place. [4-11-63]
Then, dreaded by the fear of curse that monkey Vali does not aspire
to enter the great mountain Rishyamuka, oh, people's lord, Rama, or
he does not even wish to look at it. Thus Sugreeva continued his
narration. [4-11-64]

Like Rishyasringa cursed King Parikshit uninformed in Mahābhārata, Vāli too was cursed uninformed by Matanga Muni in Rāmāyana.

Thanks Sir.. Can you share your email id so that i can directly contact you in case of doubts
